# Placing a central header in each row in a GraphicsGrid

Tags: plotting, charts

Suppose I have a `GraphicsGrid` with the following format:

```
GraphicsGrid[{{Subscript[chart, 1, 1], Subscript[chart, 1, 2]}, {Subscript[chart, 2, 1], Subscript[chart, 2, 2]}, {Subscript[chart, 3, 1], Subscript[chart, 3, 2]}}]
```

In my grid, each row concerns the same type of information, and I would like to add a centralized heading to each of the three rows. How would I achieve that?

Comment: Just in general, I have a bad experience with `GraphicsGrid`. It seems to have all kinds of bugs if the size of images is not always the same for example. `Grid` seems to be the most stable alignment tool. If more advance placement is needed, I would embed your figures in a graphics using `Inset`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is ok to use `Grid`, you can do

```
charts = Array[BarChart[Range @ Times[##]] &, {3, 2}];
rowlabels = {"row:" <> ToString[#], SpanFromLeft} & /@ Range[Length @ charts]; 
Grid @ Riffle[rowlabels, charts]
```

[image]

For labeling each column, you can do:

```
columnLabels = {"column1", "column2"};
Grid[Prepend[charts, columnLabels]]
```

[image]

Comment: I think Grid would be fine. But the effect I am looking for is (in your example) not two headings, but one heading placed in the center (in the white space between "column1" and "columns2")

Comment: @user120911, please see the updated version.

Comment: How do I place my charts (stated above) into the array? I have tried:

    charts = Array[{{Subscript[chart, 1, 1], Subscript[chart, 1, 2]}, {Subscript[chart, 2, 1], Subscript[chart, 2, 2]}, {Subscript[chart, 3, 1], Subscript[chart, 3, 2]}} &, {3, 2}];

Without the desired effect.

Comment: @user120911,  you can do `charts = {{Subscript[chart, 1, 1], Subscript[chart, 1, 2]}, {Subscript[chart, 2, 1], Subscript[chart, 2, 2]}, {Subscript[chart, 3, 1], Subscript[chart, 3, 2]}}` or `charts =  Array[Subscript[chart, ##]&, {3,2}]`.

Comment: Selecting the cell finally allows saving the assembled Grid in the desired graphics format.